# Is it possible to create an arbitrary Scikit learn decision tree from a table?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, decision-tree

Let's say I have a table describing a decision tree - each node and its feature, threshold(split point), and its left and right daughter nodes - or the prediction value, in case this is a leaf node (here signified by `status==-1`).

```
tree_structure = """ # (simplified example for clarity)
#   left_daughter right_daughter split_var split_point status prediction
1               2             3        2  394.250000      1          0
2               -1             -1       -1   0.0         -1          1
3               -1             -1       -1   0.0         -1          2
"""

# Convert the tree structure to a DataFrame
lines = tree_structure.strip().split("\n")
header = lines[0].split()
tree_data = [line.split() for line in lines[1:]]
df_tree = pd.DataFrame(tree_data, columns=header)
```

Is it possible to translate this table / DataFrame to a scikit learn decision tree?

I need this to be a scikit learn type data structure for down stream applications that require it specifically - code that constructs a tree and predicts on it is sadly insufficient for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

traverse_tree(df, node_idx, sample)
I created a recursive function `traverse_tree` that traverses the decision tree represented by you df to make a prediction for a sample you provide.

The parameters I included:

- `df`: The df of the decision tree
- `node_idx`: is the index of the
  current node in the df that is I want to evaluate
- `sample`: the dictionary that represents the input sample for which a prediction is being made

If the current node (node_idx) is a leaf node, the function will return the prediction value for that node.
If the current node is not a leaf node, it will evaluate the split condition based on the `split_var` and `split_point` columns. Here comes the recursivity because it will then call itself on either the left or right daughter node, depending on the split condition.

As for `predict(df, samples)`, it will predict the output for a list of samples using the decision tree represented by the df.
I started iterating through each sample in the samples list. Then for each sample, I call the traverse_tree function, starting from the root of the tree (index 0), and collect the predictions.

```
import pandas as pd

tree_structure = """
1               2             3        2  394.250000      1          0
2               -1            -1       -1   0.0         -1          1
3               -1            -1       -1   0.0         -1          2
"""

header = ["index", "left_daughter", "right_daughter", "split_var", "split_point", "status", "prediction"]

tree_data = [line.split() for line in tree_structure.strip().split("\n")]
df_tree = pd.DataFrame(tree_data, columns=header).apply(pd.to_numeric)  

def traverse_tree(df, node_idx, sample):
    node = df.iloc[node_idx]
    
    if node['status'] == -1:
        return node['prediction']
    
    if sample[int(node['split_var'])] <= node['split_point']:
        return traverse_tree(df, int(node['left_daughter']) - 1, sample)
    else:
        return traverse_tree(df, int(node['right_daughter']) - 1, sample)

def predict(df, samples):
    return [traverse_tree(df, 0, sample) for sample in samples]

samples = [{2: 395}, {2: 390}]
predictions = predict(df_tree, samples)
print(predictions)  # Output will be based on the decision tree structure
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Amira.
My problem is not to predict from the tree, but to have a Scikit Learn decision tree for downstream applications that require this datatype specifically.

I will amend my question accordingly.